# Need Help installing Ubuntu 13.04!

Tags: system-installation

Need Help installing Ubuntu 13.04!

I'm a newbie, trying to install Linux for the first time.  I purchased a small 14" Asus with Windows 8 and hate the new Windows 8!  I have tried downloading Ubuntu 13.04 and installing it as a dual boot for now, but I keep getting an error.  The machine will power up and give me an option to either enter Windows or Ubuntu.   Windows works, but Ubuntu won't launch.  It will just display a windows error.

What's the correct steps to installing Ubuntu?

Thanks,
BigMike75

Sorry, I have been on the road lately. Here is the error that I keep getting.

http://i1310.photobucket.com/albums/s659/Mike_Scamardo/null_zps428050ae-1.jpg

Comment: Please update  your question to include the error message.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Also, on what screen do you get the option to choose between Ubuntu and Windows? Is it grub (the default Ubuntu bootloader, has a purple-ish background) or the default Windows boot manager (which I believe is just a black screen with choices on it)?

Comment: What is the error? If we don't know than we can't help you, sadly.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? With WUBI or a live CD?

Comment: I have tried installing it three different ways.  I first tried downloading it and then using the windows installer - failed, then

Comment: tried making a bootable USB - failed, and finally dug up a few blank DVDs to burn - failed.  The USB and DVD both installed, went through the prompts, rebooted, pulled up a blue screen, and allowed you to choose Ubuntu or Windows.  Windows still works, but Ubuntu shows the above Error with both the DVD install and the USB.  I also tried a few different sources for downloads and even tried downloading 12.04, but I'm consistently getting the same error!

Comment: Well I found out how to access my BIOS through Windows 8.  It's not accessed anymore through push any button during boot up, but it is now accessed through a sub category in the PC settings in Windows 8.

Comment: I went in and changed the settings to boot directly from a bootable media.  In this case, I used the Ubuntu 12.04 bootable DVD that I had made.  The All showed OK for each category.  Finally CASPER erased the temp files, told me to eject the boot CD, and then nothing..  I pressed enter, and the computer went into reboot.  This time when the computer rebooted, it went straight to a boot loader for removable bootable DVDs/USBs.  It prompts you to press any key to begin, and now I can't figure out what to do next.  Please HELP this Newbie before his wife founds out he screwed up our laptop!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have somewhat got things figured out.  In WINDOWS 8 "hate it" goto far right, pull up settings, select PC settings, and turn on boot from CD/DVD or USB.  Load Ubuntu 13.04 that you made before on an USB or DVD.  Go through setup in Ubuntu and allow it to install. I choose install along side Win8 for now.  Remove drive and reboot computer.  On my Asus with its high speed start BIOS "which are configured for Win8", click and hold escape button as soon as the ASUS LOGO appears, must time it just right.  In BIOS turn on Legacy and make Ubuntu the first boot priority.  Now reboot again. This time on reboot, the computer should boot into Grub and allow you to choose what Operating System to start.

Things are working for now, but I'm probable going to try and put Ubuntu on its own separate partition, away from Win8.

Comment: Or...when you are done banging on the windows enough, just clean install Ubuntu

Comment: That's the eventual plan, but Im still getting use to Ubuntu and figuring out a bug or two first.